# What is the recommended way to watch for changes in a Couchbase document?

Tags: couchbase, change-tracking

I want to use Couchbase but I want to implement change tracking in a few areas similar to the way RethinkDB does it.

There appears to be a hand full of ways to have changes pushed to me from a Couchbase server.

- DCP
- TAP
- XDCR

Which one is the correct choice, or is there a better method?

---

**UPDATE**

---

Thanks @Kirk!
Thanks! it looks like DCP does not have a 100% production ready API today (5/19/2015). Your blog ref helped me decide to use XDCR today and migrate to DCP as soon as an official API is ready.

For XDCR this [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/scalabl3/couchbase-xdcr-ruby-sinatra) has been helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now the only fully supported way is XDCR as Kirk mentioned already. If you want to save time implementing it, you might want to base your code on this: https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-capi-server - it implements server side of the XDCR protocol (v1). The ElasticSearch plugin is based on this CAPI server, for example. XDCR is a good choice if your application is a server/service that can wait for incoming connections, so Couchbase (or the administrator) controls how and when Couchbase replicates data to your service.

Depending on what you want to accomplish, DCP might end up being a better choice later, because it's conceptually different from XDCR. Any DCP-based solution would be pull-based (from your code's side), so you have more fine-grained, programmatical, control over how and when to connect to a Couchbase bucket, and how to distribute your connections across different processes if necessary. For a more in-depth example of using DCP, take a look at the Couchbase-Kafka connector here: https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-kafka-connector

Answer (score 1):

DCP is the proper choice for this if how it works fits your use case and you can write an application to consume the stream as there is no official API...yet. Here is a blog post about doing this in java by one of the Couchbase Solutions Engineers, **http://nosqlgeek.blogspot.de/2015/05/dcp-magic.html**

TAP is basically deprecated at this point. It is still in the product, but DCP is far superior to it in most every fashion.

XDCR could be used, as it uses DCP, but you'd have to write a plug-in for XDCR. So you'd just be better off to write one directly to consume the DCP stream.

Comment: Thanks! it looks like DCP does not have a 100% production ready API today (5/17/2015). Your blog ref helped me decide to use XDRC today and migrate to DCP as soon as an official API is ready.

For XDRC this [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/scalabl3/couchbase-xdcr-ruby-sinatra) has been helpful.